# How to convert html to pdf on an arm32 without installing wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, arm, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to convert html documents to pdfs on an arm32 (NXP i.MX6 ARM Cortex A9). I am writing the application in C# as an .NetCore application. The problem I have is that none of the things I've tried work and I have yet to find a solution to why.

I have tried to use several external libraries to do this, most of which only work for Windows according to their support teams, so the reason *they* don't work is obvious (eg EvoPdf, SelectPdf, HiQPdf and others). The ones I have tried that I think should work for linux are Ironpdf, wrappers to wkHtmlToPdf (OpenHtmlToPdf, SharkPdf etc), pdfTron and headless chrome. They all give different errors:

**Ironpdf** complains that the libraries are not installed (I have emailed their support so they might solve this). The IronPdf.Installation.LinuxAndDockerDependenciesAutoConfig = true is set in my code but I still get the error telling me to set it to true.

```
One or more errors occurred. (The Docker or Linux image is missing dependencies for IronPDF.
Please read https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/docker-linux/
You may alternatively set IronPdf.Installation.LinuxAndDockerDependenciesAutoConfig = true to automatically resolve this issue.)
```

**OpenHtmlToPdf** has wkHtmlToPdf included but it gives a Permission Denied Error.

```
   at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setUser, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.HtmlToPdfConverterProcess.Convert(ConversionSource conversionSource)
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.DocumentBuilder.ReadContentUsingTemporaryFile(String temporaryFilename)
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.DocumentBuilder.Content()
   at OpenHTML2pdf.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

**wkHtmlToPdf**-wrappers with wkHtmlToPdf externally says it can't find wkHtmlToPdf (I can't install it so this one is obvious why it doesn't work)

**pdfTron** says it can't load one of the libraries it uses.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'PDFNetC' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libPDFNetC: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at pdftron.PDFNetPINVOKE.TRN_PDFDocCreate(IntPtr& doc)
   at pdftron.PDF.PDFDoc..ctor()
```

**Headless chrome** gives a navigation error but it should find the correct file.

```
$ chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file1.pdf --no-margins file1.html  
[0930/085730.493897:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected 
[0930/085730.494843:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected 
[0930/085730.514971:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(100)] Navigation to  failed
```

Does anyone have a solution to any of these errors or a tip about something to use that might work? I feel like I can't get any further on my own.

Comment: you came to any good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Macports has a wkhtmltopdf arm64 port for the Mac M1 machines. Perhaps you could adapt their build script to arm32. https://ports.macports.org/port/wkhtmltopdf/details/

For my label printing usage, wkhtmltopdf doesn't generate very accurate results.  I've resorted to creating a c# wrapper for libHaru (http://libharu.org/) to generate pdf's directly.

Recently I've spotted nuget package Haru.Net, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Haru.Net From the Readme: "Libharu (Haru FREE PDF Library) .NET wrapper for net451+ and netstandard2.0 (including netcore). The package consists of precompiled binaries for win32, win64, linux64 (tested on CentOS 7) linux arm32, linux arm64 and MacOS."